# Cannot make cron work

Tags: cron

This is my first question to the group.  I hope it's clear enough.  I am setting the time for every minute.  I am including information from a terminal.  Hopefully that will be clear enough.

```
steve@steve-pc:~$ ps aux | grep cron

root      1075  0.0  0.0  38428  3180 ?        Ss   09:15   0:00 /usr/sbin/cron -f

$ crontab -e

PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

SHELL=/bin/bash

MAILTO=steve

* * * * * /home/steve/scripts/beep.sh

crontab: installing new crontab

steve@steve-pc:~$ cat ./scripts/beep.sh
#!/bin/sh
echo '\a'

notify-send "cron working"

$ grep CRON /var/log/syslog
Sep  9 09:21:01 steve-pc CRON[3618]: (steve) CMD (/home/steve/scripts/beep.sh"/n")
Sep  9 09:21:01 steve-pc CRON[3617]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Sep  9 10:49:01 steve-pc CRON[5099]: (steve) CMD (/home/steve/scripts/beep.sh)
Sep  9 10:49:01 steve-pc CRON[5098]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

Comment: What's not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't actually know much about notify-send but I do know crontabs :)

Firstly, remember that cron processes are being run from the very guts of your system (traditionally from init, I dunno if the gits have changed of late :)

So, you can't assume that the commands you want executed by cron will be in *its* PATH.

The easiest way around this is to specify a full path to the commands you run, for instance use /usr/bin/notify-send as opposed to just notify-send.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you Christopher.  I'll take the notify-send out of the script and just leave the echo statement.  That is the ascii bell character and it makes a sound when I run it from a terminal.  Same with the script.  It runs fine from the terminal.

Comment: I’m afraid cron  jobs don’t work that way. Cron  is a system demon. It doesn’t know who you are or where you are so I can’t send you things like beeps or notification sounds.

Comment: Thanks again, Christopher.  I had both a beep and a notification in my script and neither were working.  Your last comment sent me in the right direction.  I had the script output something to a text file and then read the file.  I guess cron has been working all along.  I just didn't know it.

Comment: BTW Christopher.  I tried to upvote your answer but I guess I'm not allowed yet.